# Capyabara webkit cant connect to port 0 on 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby, macos, qt, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have used the following gems,

```
capybara-webkit (1.1.1 b7d6be1)
capybara (2.1.0)
Using Qt version 4.8.6
OSX 10.8.5
```

The code I have used is,

```
Capybara.app_host = "https://www.google.co.in"
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
Capybara.run_server = false 
visit "/"
```

When i try and :visit a path, it get this following error,

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
Referenced from: /Users/sunilkumar/personal/capybara-scraper/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/capybara-webkit-b7d6be163c3f/bin/webkit_server
Reason: image not found
/Users/sunilkumar/personal/capybara-scraper/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/capybara-webkit-b7d6be163c3f/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:107:in `initialize': Can't assign requested address - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 0 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

Being stuck on this for quite some time now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We are having the same issue, did you ever solve this problem?  If so, could you post a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, see: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/644

Comment: Nope, I finally moved into mechanize. Could you please post it here if you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
Referenced from: /Users/erma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@huddle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.2.0/bin/webkit_server
Reason: image not found
(see @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit)
```

All I did was gem uninstall capybara-webkit and then did a bundle install to reinstall. And then everything worked.

Comment: Once I was done with that, I started getting this on mac - 'webkit_server failed to start. (Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError)'

Comment: @Sunil, were you ever able to fix that? Might not remember how with it being so long ago. Thanks!